# Clarifications on Maintenance jobs & CDC on upgrade to ENTERPRISE EDITION

Tags: maintenance, change-data-capture

Raising these on behalf of our DBA team. We are looking at moving to ENTERPRISE SQL SERVER 2022 soon and would need help clarifying a few things:

We are looking at a 3-NODE setup:
(1) NODE-1: Primary
(2) NODE-2: Synchronous Secondary (same region as Primary)
(3) NODE-3: Asynchronous Secondary (separate region).

Out Plan: Use NODE-2 for HA and NODE-3 for DR & Reporting purposes. We plan to schedule the backup jobs (full, incremental) on NODE-3.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Scheduling Maintenance jobs: On which NODE would you recommend MAINTENANCE jobs (Index rebuild, re-org) to be scheduled?  Say we do it on NODE-2 (Synchronous Secondary). Would these automatically sync to other instances (PRIMARY and Asynchronous Secondary)?
2. CDC Scripts: We have CDC enabled in some of our tables. In which of these NODES should we run these scripts so that it is automatically available in other nodes)?  Does it always have to be PRIMARY?
3. CDC Scripts: Do these CDC scripts automatically be available in all other NODES once we execute them in, say, PRIMARY?  Will the JOBS be created automatically in other NODES, or do we need to do something manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: FWIW Index Maintenance is wasteful and a waste, so you probably don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Only the writable node can modify data, so index rebuilds, change data capture jobs, anything that modifies data all have to occur on the primary.
You can offload the backups to the synchronous secondary, but in our shop, we prefer the primary for our backups, just out of habit more than anything.

You'll want to create the jobs on all nodes, with some logic that checks:

```
if I am primary 
     ( 
     do the job;
     )
else (
     quit gracefully without an error;
     )
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is an example of how I check:

```
--check if this server is the primary node of an AAG or not

DECLARE @role_desc varchar(20)

IF( HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME ('sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states', 'OBJECT', 'execute') = 1)

    BEGIN

    -- if this is not an AG server then return 'PRIMARY'
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM sys.DATABASES d INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states hars ON d.replica_id = hars.replica_id)
        SELECT @role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
    ELSE
    -- else return if there is AN PRIMARY availability group PRIMARY else 'SECONDARY
        IF EXISTS( SELECT hars.role_desc FROM sys.DATABASES d INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states hars ON d.replica_id = hars.replica_id WHERE hars.role_desc = 'PRIMARY' )
        SELECT @role_desc = 'PRIMARY' 
    ELSE
        SELECT @role_desc = 'SECONDARY' 
    END
ELSE
    SELECT @role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE @role_desc = 'PRIMARY')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'This is where the actual work goes'
    END
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the tip.  Will have the team check it out.